# LWJGL, faild to find suitable pixel format

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl, glfw

When i try to run [this tutorial](https://www.gitbook.com/book/lwjglgamedev/3d-game-development-with-lwjgl/details)'s code it gives my a "failed to find suitable pixel format"

```
    glfwDefaultWindowHints();
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 4);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 0);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);

    windowHandle = glfwCreateWindow(width, height, title, NULL, NULL);
    if(windowHandle==NULL){
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed to create the GLFW window");
    }
```

These are the lines the Problem comes from. (according to the stacktrace) When debugging the code step by step everything works fine until the glfwCreateWindow is called. width is 800 and height is 600 so, defnitly no problem for a 27" monitor. I even used OpenGL Extensions Viewer to verify that this particular resolution is supported .

My System: Im on a MacBook pro from 2011 with lates Sierra installed, IDE is netbeans, and according to OpenGL Extensions Viewer the installed OpenGL version is 3.3.

Comment: If your maximum OpenGL version is 3.3, why do you try to get a 4.0 context? It's not really surprising that the window doesn't open then.

Comment: yeah i got this GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR a little wrong, now i setted major and minor both to 3 (which...is version 3.3) but, now it creates the window but crashes with a SIGSEGV error apparently when it comes to the line glClearColor which is called later in the code. im still trying to figure out, what the problem is, becuase in the previous chapter this method was called as well and worked just fine...

Comment: Ok i got it. I overlooked a view lines of code to make the context, set the swap intervall and stuff. sorry for that one -.-. case closed